# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'start' was corrupted

Tags: c, string, function, unicode

I get the above debugging problem from the function readString. I believe it has something to do with the way 'start' is defined in the function. The 0x07 in the array changes depending on the length of the following string. This string should say 'testing' in unicode.

```
int main(){
    char readbuffer[] = {0x07, 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x67};
    char *buf = readbuffer;
    uint32_t *stringread = (uint32_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
    *stringread = readString(buf);
    }

    uint32_t readString(char *buf)
    {
         uint32_t *start = (uint32_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
         int len;

         len = protobuf_readVarint(buf, &buf);
         memcpy (&start, buf, len);
         buf += len;

         return start;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
     memcpy (&start, buf, len);
```

you are attempting to copy the contents of `buf` to `&start` (the address of the pointer variable `start`, that is in fact an address on the stack) instead of `start` (referring to the address of the memory buffer `start` is pointing to). This is what corrupts your stack.

Apart from this, there are several other smaller issues in your code:

- you have no bounds checking, so if `len` is > 4, `memcpy` will again silently write past the end of the memory block pointed to by `start`, corrupting memory;
- you allocate a memory block within `readString()` which you never `free`, leading to a memory leak; if you are absolutely sure that `len` will never be more than 4, it would be simpler to use just a plain local variable:

  ```
   uint32_t start;
   ...
   memcpy (&start, buf, len);
  ```

  note that in this case it is correct to pass `&start` to `memcpy`!
- `buf += len` will have no effect outside `readString()` since `buf` is passed by value, thus changes to it within the function affect only its local copy, not the original.

Comment: len will be greater than 4. does this mean I have to use memcpy(start,..) And how should I allocate the memory for start properly?

Comment: @franklin, you should first get the needed length from the call `len = protobuf_readVarint(...)`, then allocate a buffer of that length: `uint32_t *start = malloc(len)`. (assuming that `protobuf_readVarint()` returns the number of bytes read, not words or `uint32`s or something else.)

Answer (score 1):

Peter answered your question. Besides I would advice you to use

```
len = max(protobuf_readVarint(buf, &buf),sizeof(uint32_t));
```

or catch when the first argument is bigger than the second because otherwise you write too much into the argument start. Also you have a memory leak which could be fixed with:

```
uint32_t readString(char *buf)
{
     uint32_t start;
     int len;

     len = max(protobuf_readVarint(buf, &buf),sizeof(uint32_t));
     memcpy ((void*)&start, buf, len);
     buf += len;

     return start;

}
```